# Problem While Installing Netbeans 7.3 On Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: installation, netbeans, jdk

I just downloaded the latest version of Netbeans on my Ubuntu and made sure to do the same with JDK as well. Problem is, every time I try to install Netbeans, this message comes out:

```
"sybreed@sybreed-VGN-BZ31XT:~/Downloads$ sh netbeans-7.3-linux.sh
Configuring the installer...
Searching for JVM on the system...
Extracting installation data...
Running the installer wizard...
An error occured while initializing the NetBeans IDE installer UI.
Most probably the running JVM is not compatible with the current platform.
See FAQ at http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqUnableToPrepareBundledJdk for more information.
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_17/jre/lib/i386/xawt/libmawt.so: libXtst.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Exception:
  java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
  /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_17/jre/lib/i386/xawt/libmawt.so: libXtst.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"
```

Does anyone have a clue what that means?
P.S: If this question has already been answered, I apologize in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing `libxtst6`... you should try

```
sudo apt-get install libxtst6
```

But its weird because openjdk-7-jre depends on it.

Comment: Thanks for answering me Rémi. I did as you told me to, but it didn't fix the problem unfortunately.